# Add empty grid space to bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having an issue here, and I want to to know how to solve it properly.

I want to add a blank cell above my `Bill to:` field so everything will line up from bill to: down.

What is the proper way to do this? Also, I don't want to break the fluidness (is that a word?) of bootstrap.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: have you tried an `<hr class="custom-class"/>` (or any other `div` for that matter) and then creating your `.custom-class` with the `min-height` needed?

Comment: Can you include the code you have so far in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You could give the 'bill to' input a top margin equal to the total height of a single-line input (including padding and margins because Bootstrap uses `box-sizing: border-box`).

To avoid adding an empty space on small viewports where the layout collapses, you should add the margin above a suitable `min-width` breakpoint.

You can see the breakpoints Bootstrap itself uses here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an input there with style="visibility:hidden" inline and you're golden...

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" style="visibility:hidden">
    </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/N33euRUtGt

And better yet, add an @media query to change from `visibility:hidden` to `display:none` at the `col-md` threshold, so the gap goes away when the sections stack:

```
.show-hide{display:none;}

@media (min-width:960px){
  .show-hide{display:inline;visibility:hidden;}
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/pAJbN5jEpL